# Magnification Below 125% Default Win API (Between 101 - 124%)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, magnification-api

I am looking into the windows magnification api and I have been playing around with it, but I have a problem with the magnification defaults, Windows only allows you to increment in 25%'s at the lowest. Is it possible for me to increase this perhaps 1-5% at a time? Perhaps increase by one percent with the mouse scroll in and out?

Windows Lowest 25% Default][1]

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

```
    int xDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);
    int yDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);

    BOOL successSet = MagSetFullscreenTransform(magnificationFactor, xDlg, yDlg);
    if (successSet)
    {
        BOOL fInputTransformEnabled;
        RECT rcInputTransformSource;
        RECT rcInputTransformDest;

        if (MagGetInputTransform(&fInputTransformEnabled, &rcInputTransformSource, &rcInputTransformDest))
        {
            if (fInputTransformEnabled)
            {
                SetInputTransform(hwndDlg, fInputTransformEnabled);
            }                
        }
    }
```

successSet == false; when it isn't 1.1 anything lower fails and I realised 1.1 = 125% zoom.

Comment: Maybe we could help if you had some code to show.

Comment: Hi, Micheal, I add the code to the question, thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such limit in the magnification API.  The limitations you see on-screen were chosen by the UI developer.

Comment: Micheal Thank you very much for your reply. Yes I know, but it defaults to 25%. I passed through the float value, but if I pass through 1.05, for example. Nothing happens, but when I pass through 1.1 it zooms to 125% zoom and I need numbers lower than that. int xDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);
        int yDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);

        BOOL fSuccess = MagSetFullscreenTransform(magnificationFactor, xDlg, yDlg);
        if (fSuccess)
        {

Answer (score 1):

Both [MagSetFullscreenTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162714.aspx) and [MagSetWindowTransform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692398.aspx) take `float` input arguments. There are no restrictions as far as the [magnification factor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692402.aspx#magnification_factor) resolution goes, as long as it is at least `1.0f` and no larger than the upper bound.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes I know, but it defaults to 25%. I passed through the float value, but if I pass through 1.05, for example. Nothing happens, but when I pass through 1.1 it zooms to 125% zoom and I need numbers lower than that. int xDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);
        int yDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);

        BOOL fSuccess = MagSetFullscreenTransform(magnificationFactor, xDlg, yDlg);
        if (fSuccess)
        {